# How to construct the regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to construct a regular expression with following requirements:

- Firstly, there are a 'CTRL' or 'ALT' string.
- Then, it is followed by a '+'.
- Finally, there must be an alphanumeric character.

For Example:

'CTRL+a', 'ALT+B', 'ctrl+1', 'alt+3'.

Thank so much.

Comment: Maybe this regex help you `/^((CTRL)|(ALT))\+\w$/i`

Answer (score 0):

This answers your request:

```
/(?:ctrl|alt)\+\w+/i
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/iqXnBU/1)

Comment: It´s more or less. But, alphanumeric only can be one.

Comment: @mgp1994: Just remove `+` after `\w`.